# two different sounds need to play when hovering an image?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am a beginner in JavaScript, CSS and HTML. I have two images at the top of a bag that I want to play two different sounds when hovered. However, when I hover on either of the images they play the same sound. I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how to get the images to play two different sounds. thank you!!!

```
<script>
   function play(){
   var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
   audio.play();
             }
   </script>

<img src="Photos/crowabout.png" height="150" width="150" value="PLAY"  
onmouseover="play()" onmouseout="stop()">
 <audio id="audio" src="Sounds/divers.mp3" ></audio>


    <script>
  function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
                 }
   </script>

<img src="Photos/harptour.png" height="150" width="150" value="PLAY"  onmouseover="play()" onmouseout="stop()">
<audio id="audio" src="Sounds/cosmia.mp3" ></audio>
```

Comment: Well yes, that tends to happen when you create 2 audio elements with the same id. Instead, give each a different id and make sure your play function calls the correct one: `function play(id){ var audio = document.getElementById(id); audio.play(); }` then `onmouseover="play('audio1')"` or `onmouseover="play('audio2')"`

Comment: Also remove one of the play functions. You only need one for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, id attributes should always be unique.

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

In your code, Javascript has no way of knowing which audio element to play because both have the same id. Instead, make sure both have unique ids:

```
<audio id="audio1" src="Sounds/divers.mp3" ></audio>
<audio id="audio2" src="Sounds/cosmia.mp3" ></audio>
```

Javascript functions can include parameters. This is a way to pass along additional information to your function to use:

```
function play(id){
    var audio = document.getElementById(id);
    audio.play();
}
```

Now your play function has the parameter id. So we can pass along the correct id to play when we call the function:

```
play('audio1');
play('audio2');
```

Finally your script should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function play(id){
    var audio = document.getElementById(id);
    audio.play();
}
</script>

<img src="Photos/crowabout.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" value="PLAY" onmouseover="play('audio1');" onmouseout="stop();">
<audio id="audio1" src="Sounds/divers.mp3"></audio>

<img src="Photos/harptour.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" value="PLAY"  onmouseover="play('audio2');" onmouseout="stop()">
<audio id="audio2" src="Sounds/cosmia.mp3"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter into your `play()` funciton.

```
function play(selector){
    document.getElementById(selector).play();
}
```

Then, assign different `id` to different `<audio>`:

```
<audio id="anID" src="Sounds/divers.mp3" ></audio>
<audio id="anotherID" src="Sounds/cosmia.mp3" ></audio>
```

Then, in your inline function call:

```
<img src="Photos/crowabout.png" height="150" width="150" value="PLAY"  
onmouseover="play('anID')" onmouseout="stop()">

<img src="Photos/crowabout.png" height="150" width="150" value="PLAY"  
onmouseover="play('anotherID')" onmouseout="stop()">
```

Usually, we don't assign identical `id` to more than 1 element because it serves like an identity of the element, similar to our identity card number where each person has a unique number.

The function's parameter is like a predefined variable for the particular function. Unlike the usual variable declaration `var bla = 'bla'`, value of function parameter is given at the time of calling the function like what you see above `play('audio1')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<script>
function playDriver(){
   var audio = document.getElementById("audio-driver");
   audio.play();
             }

function playCosmia(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio-cosmia");
       audio.play();
                 }
   </script>

<img src="Photos/crowabout.png" height="150" width="150" value="PLAY"  
onmouseover="playDriver()" onmouseout="stop()">
 <audio id="audio-driver" src="Sounds/divers.mp3" ></audio>

<img src="Photos/harptour.png" height="150" width="150" value="PLAY"  onmouseover="playCosmia()" onmouseout="stop()">
<audio id="audio-cosmia" src="Sounds/cosmia.mp3" ></audio>
```